# Jira and git: How to get all branches reflected?

Tags: git, jira, atlassian-fisheye

Using a development infrastructure of git, Fisheye+Crucible, and Jira 4.2.

Commits to Fisheye-registered repositories are reflected in Jira Projects and Tickets since we configured the mappings in Jira; however, only commits on the master branch seem to be reflected. In Crucible, other branches can be chosen to search for commits for reviews.

How can I make all those branches visible in Jira?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it is a limitation of Git-Fisheye ( https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/FISHEYE/Git ):

> When FishEye indexes a Git repository, it indexes by the available branches. As it processes the commits on a branch, FishEye will assign the commit to the branch it first sees the commit on. Commits are only indexed once so if a commit belongs to multiple branches, the commit will not indexed against subsequent branches.

You may consider using - Jira Git plugin 
https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.xiplink.jira.git.jira_git_plugin

Answer (score 0):

Showing the same commit for every branch it appears on makes the commit list unreadable. [Klonfisch](https://github.com/netresearch/klonfisch/), the Jira-Gitorious-connector, does it that way.

It's unreadable and I'll probably change it. Here is an example with 5 branches:

[image]