# Jira and git: How to see all commits from a mapped repository in a project "code" view

Tags: git, jira, atlassian-fisheye

Using a development infrastructure of git, Fisheye / Crucible, and Jira 4.2.

I can see commits that mention a ticket ID in the commit message on the source tab of that ticket's page [as long as the commits are on the master branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9517866/jira-and-git-how-to-get-all-branches-reflected), ever since I mapped the Fisheye repos in Jira. That's good.

On the project page source tab however, I also only see those commits the commit messages of which reference one of the project's tickets.

How can I make every commit to the repository mapped to that project in Jira show up on the project's source tab?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know any way to change Project's Source Tab, but you can see all commits to the repository from the Fisheye gadget that you can add to your project's dashboard.

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Adding+the+FishEye+Recent+Changesets+Gadget